# is there a way to get the user location info with firebase google auth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Auth and the result that the api giving after the auth flow dosen't contain info about the user location like the country and the city. I am wondering if there's a way to get the user location info during the auth process flow with Firebase Auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Auth does not provide that information, as it would reduce the privacy of the end user.  If you want that information, you'll have to ask the user to provide it themselves.